# Site traffic goes down suddenly

Tags: seo, traffic

What are things that we need to check in priority when site traffic goes down suddenly?
I just want to know major factor which can down site traffic

Comment: It is too broad and There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.. You can see a lot of posts regarding site traffic [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=site+traffic)

Comment: @Sathiya - thanks for reply. I just want to know major factor which can down site traffic.

Comment: Questions that ask for a list of things don't fit well on this site because the voting of answers often becomes a competition between different answers.  It ends up messing wit the reputation system.

Comment: Stephen - Its fine now. I got answer from james and I satisfied by that answer..

Comment: BTW- Panda 4.1 was just released around November 23-25 2014 and quite possibly earlier. If the drop is around/between the 20th - 25th, then it could be Panda 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities.

First thing you should do is compare your Google Analytics with any algorithm updates. If there has been an update around the same time your traffic tanked, then that is likely the problem.

I would also check webmaster tools for any messages and manual penalties. This will entail a lot of work cleaning up your inbound link profile.

Another possibility could be a website error. Make sure robots.txt is not blocking things that it shouldn't, make sure that there are no robots "noindex,follow" meta tags. The former is easier to restore, I have noticed pages that have taken extreme amounts of effort to recover from the latter.

If applicable, please check your .htaccess (or equivalent) too. Errors here can cause havoc. It is possible to instruct search engines not to index pages in the .htaccess.

If you give more details, such as dates and google analytics screenshots with the dip, I can provide a more accurate response.

Comment: I might have gone on another path related to SEO if I answered this question and I would have liked your answer better! Nicely done!! BTW- Panda 4.1 was just released around November 23-25 2014 and quite possibly earlier. If the drop is around/between the 20th - 25th, then it could be Panda 4.1.